# can i use gps to track my location when i an offline

Tags: android, gps, android-maps

I want to make an app for android phones which will gives some notification when it reaches certain point . Is it possible to do it using GPS ? And is it possible to make user download maps and then use that map to track location using GPS system , i mean can i track device location without internet using GPS and gives notification when phone is offline .if it is possible then please give me some guidance how can I do it

Comment: Use the FusedLocation API to request location updates. It even provides location without internet by just using the GPS.

Comment: Thanks alot Jyotman Singh for helping me

Comment: Can i compare my gps location with maps location that is already loaded in phone ?

Comment: Didn't get your question. Please explain

Comment: i mean if i have my gps current location ok ... then how i will come to know that i reached school,college etc so that i can notify user ?

Comment: try searching about geofencing

Answer (score 0):

you can get location with no cell tower by satellite. it is free and called fine location. cell towers are less accurate form of location. The map used to display the location must have a connection to the internet however and you get maps via [google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/) This is free to develop apps but when you sell the app google takes a cut.

Answer (score 0):

yeah we can get our current location in offline by using FUSED LOCATION

[refer here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)